# How can I use REGEXMATCH and SPLIT in a filter in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have two data sets:

- Data set 1 is data from our Sales team
- Data set 2 is data from our Finance team

The common element between these two sets is the **Invoice ID** column (col A in data set 1 and col E in data set 2). However, in data set 1, this data is stored as an array, and in data set 2, each value of the array is displayed on its own row.

**GOAL**

I'd like to be able to enrich data set 2 (cols F & G) with the data from data set 1, however, I'm having trouble making that work. I've tried using `=FILTER(A3:A7, REGEXMATCH(TEXT(E3, "0"), TEXT(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A3:A7, ",")), "0")))`, but that gives me the following error: "FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.". I understand that this happens because of the `SPLIT` function, but I don't know how else to go about this.

The sheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQSBE97zA6SCvRvIb7FGp89qsoJkND9i4NWwYBQ5pFQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Any help is super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. The following single formula will produce all results for F3:G ...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(E3:E="",,VLOOKUP("*"&"%"&E3:E&"%"&"*",{REGEXREPLACE("%"&A3:A&"%","[,\s]","%"),B3:C},{2,3},FALSE)))`

The `%` symbol is just used to "pad" every element from Col A and Col E in something unique in order to differentiate search term `1` from, say, `14` (i.e., the `VLOOKUP` will search for `%1%` instead of just `1`, which will not be found in `%14%`, etc.) The `%` symbol has no special meaning; it could have been any unique character we were sure wouldn't normally turn up in Col A or Col E.

`REGEXREPLACE` replaces all commas and spaces with this special `%` character in addition to the front and back placements. So a Col-A list like `1, 14` would be seen by sheets at this point as `%1%%14%`.

The `*` is a wildcard symbol that, appended front and back to the search term, which will allow it to be found in elements of Col A that contain lists.

Results from the second and third columns (e.g., `{2,3}`) of the virtual array are returned.

Comment: Just perfect @Erik Tyler. Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on-

```
=FILTER($B$3:$B$7,ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(SPLIT($A$3:$A$7,", ")=E3),SEQUENCE(Columns(ArrayFormula(SPLIT($A$3:$A$7,", ")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Harun24HR. There is maybe just one other thing that I probably should have mentioned, which is that, while in that sheet, Data set 1 is limited to only rows 3 to 7, in my real data set 1, that range is continuously increasing.

I tried to re-write your formula as `=FILTER($B$3:$B,ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(SPLIT($A$3:$A,", ")=E3),SEQUENCE(Columns(ArrayFormula(SPLIT($A$3:$A,", ")))))))`, but ended up getting the error "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 520, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.". 

Do you know why?